# PhpOffice/PhpWord Charts - Cant show Axis, Grids, Labels

Tags: php, phpword

Im using the Sample_32_Chart.php from PhpOffice/PhpWord...

It's working, but I would love that my charts get axis, series, labels, titles, etc... on them.

Tried looking into the documentation
http://phpoffice.github.io/PHPWord/docs/master/classes/PhpOffice.PhpWord.Element.Chart.html

But there is nothing any close to my needs.

Any help would be amazing.

Some code

```
<?php
include_once 'Sample_Header.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter;

// New Word document
echo date('H:i:s'), ' Create new PhpWord object', EOL;

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('size' => 14, 'bold' => true), array('keepNext' => true, 'spaceBefore' => 240));
$phpWord->addTitleStyle(2, array('size' => 14, 'bold' => true), array('keepNext' => true, 'spaceBefore' => 240));

// 2D charts
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addTitle(htmlspecialchars('2D charts', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), 1);
$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('colsNum' => 2, 'breakType' => 'continuous'));

$chartTypes = array('pie', 'doughnut', 'bar', 'column', 'line', 'area', 'scatter', 'radar');
$twoSeries = array('bar', 'column', 'line', 'area', 'scatter', 'radar');
$threeSeries = array('bar', 'line');
$categories = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$series1 = array(1, 3, 2, 5, 4);
$series2 = array(3, 1, 7, 2, 6);
$series3 = array(8, 3, 2, 5, 4);

foreach ($chartTypes as $chartType) {
    $section->addTitle(ucfirst($chartType), 2);
    $chart = $section->addChart($chartType, $categories, $series1);
    $chart->getStyle()->setWidth(Converter::inchToEmu(2.5))->setHeight(Converter::inchToEmu(2));

    if (in_array($chartType, $twoSeries)) {
        $chart->addSeries($categories, $series2);
    }
    if (in_array($chartType, $threeSeries)) {
        $chart->addSeries($categories, $series3);
    }
    $section->addTextBreak();
}

// 3D charts
$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('breakType' => 'continuous'));
$section->addTitle(htmlspecialchars('3D charts', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), 1);
$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('colsNum' => 2, 'breakType' => 'continuous'));

$chartTypes = array('pie', 'bar', 'column', 'line', 'area');
$multiSeries = array('bar', 'column', 'line', 'area');
$style = array('width' => Converter::cmToEmu(5), 'height' => Converter::cmToEmu(4), '3d' => true);
foreach ($chartTypes as $chartType) {
    $section->addTitle(ucfirst($chartType), 2);
    $chart = $section->addChart($chartType, $categories, $series1, $style);
    if (in_array($chartType, $multiSeries)) {
        $chart->addSeries($categories, $series2);
        $chart->addSeries($categories, $series3);
    }
    $section->addTextBreak();
}

// Save file
echo write($phpWord, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);
if (!CLI) {
    include_once 'Sample_Footer.php';
}
```

Which is the Sample_32_Chart.php, in this link I found someone talking about this functions already begin added, but dunno how to use them.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/576

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alberto, did you ever figure out how to add axis, series, labels, titles, etc... to the chart in PHPWord?

Comment: Unfortunately, no @PHPDave. I went to PHPExcel instead. Got some nice looking charts with it.

Comment: Awesome I'll have to look into that.  Did you then export the chart from PHPExcel and import it into PHPWord?  I'm contemplating just porting in the xml and manually adding the data series

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on this a little bit and came up with some modifications that can be made to pass raw xml graph settings and have PHPWord output it.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/957 - See my second comment on that thread